# Proving Big O notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Prove **5n^2+ 2n -1 = O(n^2)**.
This is what I have attempted so far:

```
    5n^2 + 2n -1 <= 5n^2 + 2n^2 -n2 for n>1
    5n^2+ 2n -1 <= 6n^2  for n>1
    5n^2+ 2n -1 = O(n^2) [ c = 6n^2, n0 = 1 ]
```

Is this the right way of proving Big O notation?

Comment: The first line is unnecessary (and in fact not correct)

Comment: Great Thanks! One more question say prove 5n^2+ 2n -1 = O(n^3) - Would that become false?

Comment: Note that c=6 and not 6n^2

Comment: You only need to show that your expression is bounded by some constant multiplied by `n^2`, q.v. here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: Also, 5n^2 is O(n^3)

Comment: @BlackBear Can you please explain that?

Comment: @SLA It actually suffices to show that the limit `(5n^2+ 2n -1)/(n^2)=constant` as `n` approaches infinity, which is obviously true (the limit is `5` in your case).

Answer (score 4):

To prove that your expression is `O(n^2)`, you need to show that it is bounded by `M*n^2`, for some constant `M` and some minimum `n` value.  By inspection, we can show that your expression is bounded by `10*n^2`, for `n=10`:

For `n = 10`:

```
5n^2 + 2n -1 <= 10*n^2
500 + 20 - 1 <= 1000
519 <= 1000
```

We can also show that the expression is bounded by `10*n^2` for any value `n` *greater* than 10:

For `n > 10`:

```
5n^2 + 2n -1 <= 10*n^2
5*(10+i)^2 + 2*(10+i) -1      <= 10*(10+i)^2
5*(i^2 + 20i + 100) + 2i + 19 <= 10*(i^2 + 20i + 100)
2i + 19 <= 5*(i^2 + 20i + 100)
2i + 19 <= 5i^2 + 100i + 500
5i^2 + 98i + 481 >= 0, which is true for `i > 0`
```

Here is a link to the Wikipedia article on Big-O notation:

**https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation**

**Update:**

Note that in practice in order to label your expression `O(n^2)` we won't resort to such an ugly written proof.  Instead, we will just recognize that the `n^2` term will dominate the expression for large `n`, and that the overall behavior will be `O(n^2)`.  And your expression is also `O(n^3)` (and `O(n^4)`, etc.).

Comment: So it will be bounded by n**3 for n=10, so it's also `O(n**3)`, even though it's less useful to write.

Comment: @EricDuminil Yes it is also `O(n^3)` but usually folks try to get the lowest bound possible.  Telling you that I can do your laundry in 2 months or less, while true, is functionally useless, because you need it by the end of the week.

Comment: :) You're totally right. It's just that the OP mentioned that he also needs to prove it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

it looks fine , I'm thinking that if you are doing it for your assignment work or other formal work then you can also do it in more formal way like for selecting the value of constant ( c ) such as by f(n)/g(n).Otherwise it looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

We have f(n) = 5*n^2+2*n-1 and g(n) = n^2

In order to prove f(n) = O(g(n)), we just need to find 2 constants, namely c > 0 and n_0, s.t. f(n) <= c.g(n) for all n >= n0.

Let's choose some value of c = 5.5 say. Let's evaluate and plot f(n) and c*g(n). As we can see from the plot and we can also show it theoretically since n^2/2 - 2*n + 1 = (n^2-4*n+2)/2 = ((n-2)^2-2)/2 >= 0 for all n >= 4, it implies that 5*n^2+2*n-1 <= 5.5*n^2 for all n >= n0 = 4. Hence, f(n) = O(g(n)). (proved)

[image]